# Power Bi Compare two tables and get values that do not matched criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax

i have 2 tables and, i would like to check if table 1 (Type_Sorting) == (CCSClassCode_Type) is matched with table 2 (_Type Sorting) == (_CCS Class Type):

for example, you can see vi got the wrong value in table 1 (CCSClassCode_Type)
and, the right value is `XLB`as you can see in table 2 (_CCS Class Type) not `ULM`,
the idea of table 2 to check if people type the right values, Please not that table 2  (_CCS Class Type) have duplicate values

thank you in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this like that:

```
Table 2 = 

Var trt = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(Table_2, "XX"
, COMBINEVALUES(",",Table_2[_CCS Class Type],Table_2[_Type Sorting]))
return

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table_1[Column1]
, Table_1[CCSClassCode_Type]
, Table_1[Type_Sorting]
, FILTER(ALL(Table_1[CCSClassCode_Type],Table_1[Type_Sorting]), not( COMBINEVALUES(",",Table_1[CCSClassCode_Type],Table_1[Type_Sorting])
in trt )

))
```

[image]

Comment: error :/
The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: Can you post your "version" of statement (did you put this in NewTable on "Data" tab in powerbi-desktop?). I check my pbi file and everything is working as shown in example.

Comment: yes, I did, but the problem I don't know why you added column 1 {1,2,3,4} in both tables? i am not sure if you have 5min I guess i can shear my screen with you ?

Comment: I add this column to show that we can also pull info, for eg about ticket number or from your data [Element]. If you want just a list of invalid type_Sorting/ CCSClass then remove this additional column.

Comment: you can check it https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Translated-Spanish-Desktop/power-bi-comparar-2-tablas/m-p/1473565#M140157

I hope you will get better view